# Message in side client visual basic application?

Tags: vb.net, optimization, software-design, search-suggestion

I have a Visual Basic application, and there are a lot of clients using it. Every XX days I make some updates to the source, and after that, I contact every client to tell them that there is a new version of the application.

But I realize that I have a few clients using an old version of the system.
Is there a way (by this I mean some kind of code, library, functions, etc.) to modify/update my master source, so that if a user is using an old version of the application, some kind of message appears after a successful log in into the system?

> Message: "You are using v.1.00 and this is an old version of the
>   system. Try to update to the newest version, v.2.01"

Additional to the information described above, in my VB application I used some parts of VB.net code for some actions that require connections to Internet web pages.

Any suggestions/help/comments or guidance would be very helpful!

Comment: You could write an updater or watchdog app to compare data from your server to the local version.  Otherwise this is fairly broad for SO

Comment: I'll give a look/searching for this that you're commenting. Thanks @Plutonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do much about the customers who are already out there.

An easy way to implement this is to have your code retrieve an XML file from a website that you control.  That XML file would contain the most recent version number.  The code compares its version number to the version in the XML.  If they're different, you display a message.

As a bonus, your XML can include a URL that points to the newest version for download.

Comment: Thanks @DWRoelands I'll take notice of your advice.